# Does a semi-transparent overlay that only appears temporarily at game completion violate Google Adsense policy?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

On my DEV server, after a user finishes a game on the website, a semi-transparent overlay covers the whole page. The score is then shown on the overlay.
Through the overlay, you can still clearly see where google advertising would go. There is no way to accidentally click it. In fact, the advert is not clickable until the overlay is closed (and it is not possible to accidentally click the advertising when clicking close).

I've read the Google Adsense Policies and suspect that I am violating the following policy

> Google Ads may not be:
>
> Obscured by elements on a page.

The picture below shows you the overlay and advertising.
[image: example of semi-transparent overlay]

It seems the answer is pretty cut and dry, but I'm weakly hoping that by obscure they mean you can't see the advertising at all. Anyway, I'd like to see what other peoples' take is on this. As you can probably guess, for aesthetic reasons I'd really like to leave the overlay in place.

**UPDATE:**
Just to be clear, I'm not using "Adsense for Games". I'm using the Adsense meant for websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this question asked many times in various forums.   The answer is not clear.

Here is a [blog post](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/blog/use-lightbox-with-adsense/) where somebody posed the question to their Google ad rep:

> Is Lightbox is allowed with AdSense? So I shot a quick email to my Google AdSense Representative. After reviewing the sample page I provided, the AdSense representative finally sent me good news.
>
> Yes, you can use Lightbox and Google AdSense ads together on a web page without any problem. One important thing though, AdSense ads cannot not be shown in the Lightbox pop-up!

Here is a Google Product Forum that says that lightboxes are OK, as long as they fill the whole screen and don't use transparency: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/ngldkoLNIho/eInO41RpcZwJ

Other times when asked the answer is "strictly prohibited":

- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/RABJE01xqQ0/Tu6JZNsac_IJ
- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/NJRVYzKQ_Tg/cQr5BnxFnYoJ
- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/TgKGGhfJQag/D6TmwoFLvmoJ