# Is it a violation of adense policies if I blank the screen for 200ms?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, render

At this point, I'm working on the internal user experience of my site when it loads. I already got things better by making DOM elements hidden while changes are being applied to them, whilst being careful not to modify the adsense DIV box on my site.

All adsense ads on my site are fixed-size ad units.

What I'm considering doing as an attempt to reduce repainting and reflowing is encapsulating my webpage in a DIV and upon javascript execution, hide the entire DIV contents including the adsense ad unit and then showing everything again when javascript execution is finished. The execution time (as reported by webpagetest.org) takes roughly 200ms.

Here's a sample of my proposed page layout:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="wrapper">
some content in here
<!-- javascript code imported from google here -->
more content
</div>
<script>   
document.getElementByID("wrapper").style.visibility="hidden";
//post javascript processes that take 200ms here 
document.getElementByID("wrapper").style.visibility="visible";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, would blanking out the entire webpage window for 200ms (including blanking the adsense ad unit) violate adsense policies?

By blanking, I mean clearing the contents of the screen.

Comment: It's allowed, otherwise millions of sites with preloaders would have there adsense accounts revoked. Similar > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60171/does-a-semi-transparent-overlay-that-only-appears-temporarily-at-game-completion

Answer (score 1):

Blanking a page for 200ms such as for a page loader or splash screen is allowed and complies with the terms of AdSense. The only time that blanking the content will be an issue with AdSense is if you are blanking just over the AdSense section.